# Build automata based on a given regular language

Tags: automata, regular-language

Given $M$ which is a DFA for a regular language $L$,
is it possible to build DFA/NFA for the language 
$$
 L' = \{w \in L\:\:\text{s.t.}\:\: ww \in L \}
$$
and if so then how?

Comment: Is this saying, "whenever w is in L, ww is also in L" or "whenever ww is in L, w is also in L"? If the former, it's possible to define a language `K = {if w, x are in L, then wx and xw are in K` by taking two copies of the DFA for L and chaining them. K is a superset of L'. I don't think L' is regular.